# "Compact empty middle packages" is not found in new Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I want to set convenient settings after Android Studio updating: 3.1->3.3.

I have one problem: everywhere I can found empty middle packages, and I can't find the special option to compact it. Here I have just this options in 'Options Menu':

[image: screen]

You see, there are some not compacted empty middle packages:

`java,ru,randgor,mygia,v4`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Selecting the **Android** view will achieve what you want.

[image]

Comment: What did that menu drop down from?  Was that a right click or a top of app menu of some sort?

Answer (score 8):

as of the time of writing this answer the "Compact middle packages"
is located here :

[image]

<sub><sup>for some reason it was a pain in the a** to find</sup></sub>